# Is it a good practice to set a flash message in the model?

Tags: model, yii, flash-message

I'm developping some functonalities that perform some db related stuff so it should be in my active record model.

I would like to give some feedback to the user depending on the results of the db queries using [`setFlash`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser/#setFlash-detail).

So my question is: is it a good practice to set a flash message inside a model instead of a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access all these from the controller:

entry already exists - you have `$model->isNewRecord`

entry added - you have `if($model->save()) { //successful } else { //unsuccessful }`

The model should best be left to define the model, and not define which message should be displayed to the user - that's what controllers are for.

Comment: I'm not using some CActiveRecord function, my queries are performed using DAO so `$model->isNewRecord` and `$model->save()` wont be helpful but you are right I shouldn't put those message in the controller and I know how I'm gonna do it! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I would do that from my controller for sure, but why would you have to do it from Model though but it won't really get you into trouble by setting flash message from Model?

After all you finally come into controller from Model , you can then set from controller by looking at the returned values/responses from Model

Comment: Yeah but there is many possible repsonse: entry already exists, entry added, db exception, ... and I'm not sure what I should return (a boolean wont handle all case). May be return a constant, what do you think about it?

Comment: If i am to do this, i'd handle in following ways
For already existing entry,i'd check in controller at then pass to MOdel
and for db related responses, the user should only be shown the success and failure, rather than db-exception or other messages. These details would be just important for the devs, that can be tracked with loggers. 
Thankyou